# Tumblr - Bug on Edit Theme Page

Tags: css, tumblr

I am using the Redux theme and I added this:

> If this “`img`” entry already exists, we’re going to add one simple
>   piece of code to it. Within the `{ }` brackets following “`img`”, add this
>   code (in bold) just before the closing `}` bracket: **`height:auto;`**

in the `style type="text/css"` part of the code.

Since then, the photosets on the "Edit Theme" page show Tumblr error messages. This doesn't happen on single image posts.

I've installed new themes, reinstalled Redux but it stays the same. Here is what is on the inspect bit when I right click on the error on my photoset:

```
<p class="error-message-text" data-localization="message">
Whatever you were looking for doesn't currently exist at this address.
Unless you were looking for this error page, in
which case: Congrats! You totally found it.
</p>
```

How do I fix this?

```
We need to see the code blocks for your tumblr template. And also a link to the live tumblr would be helpful. Are there errors being thrown in the console?
```

Please find at requested.

```
</style>
    <!--[if lt IE 7.]>
        <style type="text/css">
            #wrapper #sidebar #bottom {
                background: transparent;
            }

            #wrapper #sidebar #top #avatar {
                background: none;
            }

            #wrapper #sidebar #top #avatar img {
                border: 5px solid #f1f1f1;
```

http://biscuitsarenice.tumblr.com/

Comment: Hi Elaine, have you tried clearing your browser cache, or using a different browser? Does this only happen on the "Edit Theme" page, or does it happen on your blog too if you save the theme?

Comment: We need to see the code blocks for your tumblr template. And also a link to the live tumblr would be helpful. Are there errors being thrown in the console?